# Duplicate camera stream not working with custom frame width and height

Tags: linux, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-capture, v4l2

I have been able to duplicated my webcam stream on ubuntu with

```
 gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3
```

Im able to launch 2 simultaneous streams by

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink       
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

But if I try to change streams width and height it doesnt work

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw, width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1' ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

Error ---

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Even this isnt working --

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1  ! ximagesink -v
```

**UPDATE**
Its working now with this command, but only with framerate =30. If I change the framerate to anything else it just doesnt work at all

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=640,height=480, framerate=30/1  ! ximagesink -v
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/2147483647, format=(string)YUY2, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/2147483647, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSink:ximagesink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/2147483647, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, format=(string)BGRx
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/2147483647, format=(string)YUY2, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
```

Comment: Could  you try `videorate` after `videoscale`?  `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw, width=640,height=480, framerate=15/1  ! ximagesink -v`

Answer (score 0):

Internal data stream error appears when you pass wrong height, width or another cam parameter. Check cam resolution and framerate before you. One note, you cant change framerate by pass different value, cam have fixed set resolution and framerate, if you want change framerate use **videorate**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).